How to report the maximum value of only previous rows in a group of rows in R?
I am trying to find a way to report the maximum value of previous rows in groups of rows, using either tidyverse or data.table.
Let's say I have the following data frame, in which Start and End represent start and end frames of whichever behaviours:
Example <- data.frame(Group = c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 6)),
                      Individual = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "C"),
                      Start = c(15, 30, 35, 37, 50, 61, 66, 83, 88, 93, 108, 130),
                      End = c(26, 48, 41, 44, 72, 64, 71, 95, 91, 94, 115, 150))

I would like to create a new column, End_multi, which should take the maximum value of all previous rows in the same group.
I tried with data.table. Here is the step-by-step code:
library(data.table)

Example_dt <- as.data.table(Example)

Example_dt2 <- copy(Example_dt)
Example_dt2[, End_multi := shift(End, 1:2, type = "lag"), by = Group]

Example_dt3 <- copy(Example_dt2)
Example_dt3[, End_multi := max(unlist(shift(End, 1:2, type = "lag")), na.rm = TRUE), by = Group]

I have several issues with this code:

it does not start from the start of the group of rows, as it only takes the last 2 rows into account.
when reporting the maximum value, it reports the overall maximum of the lagged values of the group but I would like to have the maximum value in the lagged rows up to the current row.

The ideal output for me would be something like:
Example_desired <- data.frame(Group = c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 6)),
                              Individual = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "C"),
                              Start = c(15, 30, 35, 37, 50, 61, 66, 83, 88, 93, 108, 130),
                              End = c(26, 48, 41, 44, 72, 64, 71, 95, 91, 94, 115, 150),
                              End_multi = c(26, 48, 48, 48, 72, 72, 71, 95, 95, 95, 115, 150))

Do you know what I need to change in data.table to achieve this or have another way of doing it in the tidyverse?

As yuk mentioned, cummax is what you're looking for- here is a data.table solution:
setDT(Example)


#I would like to create a new column, 
# End_multi, which should 
# take the maximum value of 
# all previous rows in the same group.

Example[, `:=`(Start_multi=cummax(Start),
               End_multi=cummax(End)),
        by = Group]
Example
#    Group Individual Start   End Start_multi End_multi
#    <num>     <char> <num> <num>       <num>     <num>
# 1:     1          A    15    26          15        26
# 2:     1          B    30    48          30        48
# 3:     1          C    35    41          35        48
# 4:     1          A    37    44          37        48
# 5:     1          B    50    72          50        72
# 6:     1          C    61    64          61        72
# 7:     2          A    66    71          66        71
# 8:     2          C    83    95          83        95
# 9:     2          B    88    91          88        95
#10:     2          A    93    94          93        95
#11:     2          B   108   115         108       115
#12:     2          C   130   150         130       150

Just make sure your data is sorted as you'd like it:
Example[order(Group, Start)]

You can use cummax function:
Example_desired <- Example %>% mutate(End_multi = cummax(End), .by = "Group")

